# Swift Array where the values meet the conditions

Tags: arrays, swift

I have array and I would like to get only the records that have the field _tisk > 0 and _chodnazev = "Předkrm" or "Dezert".

How to do that? Here is code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    
    var sorted_polozky = Array<(key: String, value: Array<polozkyUcet>)>()

    struct polozkyUcet: Codable {
        let _id: Int
        let _masterid: Int
        var _rcptid: Int
        var _mnozstvi: String
        var _delene_mnozstvi: String
        let _recept: String
        var _cena: Double
        let _tisk: Int
        var _chod: Int
        var _chodnazev: String
        var _host: String
        var _popis: String
        var _cenazak: Double
    }


   

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
        let test =  [(key: "Předkrm", value: [polozkyUcet(_id: 456037, _masterid: 145138, _rcptid: 19276, _mnozstvi: "1", _delene_mnozstvi: "0", _recept: "ŠKVARKOVÁ POMAZÁNKA", _cena: 85.0, _tisk: -1, _chod: 1, _chodnazev: "Předkrm", _host: "0", _popis: "", _cenazak: 85.0)]), (key: "Hlavní chod", value: [polozkyUcet(_id: 456038, _masterid: 145138, _rcptid: 17828, _mnozstvi: "1", _delene_mnozstvi: "0", _recept: "PÁRKY OD KREJCARŮ,BRAMBOROVÁ KAŠE", _cena: 135.0, _tisk: -10, _chod: 10, _chodnazev: "Hlavní chod", _host: "0", _popis: "", _cenazak: 135.0)]), (key: "Dezert", value: [polozkyUcet(_id: 456039, _masterid: 145138, _rcptid: 3047, _mnozstvi: "0,5", _delene_mnozstvi: "0", _recept: "RAKVIČKA SE ŠLEHAČKOU", _cena: 20.0, _tisk: -30, _chod: 30, _chodnazev: "Dezert", _host: "0", _popis: "", _cenazak: 40.0), polozkyUcet(_id: 456112, _masterid: 145138, _rcptid: 1117, _mnozstvi: "1", _delene_mnozstvi: "0", _recept: "KAPR FILET NA KMÍNĚ", _cena: 168.0, _tisk: 30, _chod: 30, _chodnazev: "Dezert", _host: "0", _popis: "", _cenazak: 168.0)])]

        sorted_polozky = test
        print(sorted_polozky)   
    }
}
```

Comment: Strange having an array with (key, value) tuples as array elements, and not a dictionary. Is that what you want?

Comment: Your inner value type is an array, should only the matching elements be returned or the whole array if any element matches? And could you clean up your example so it compiles please.

Comment: @gnasher729 Array divided like this is due to use of titleForHeaderInSection in tableview

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Showing both solutions would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To filter out any tuple that has at least one element that matches the filter you can do

```
let result = test.filter {
    $0.value.contains { item in item._tisk > 0 && ["Předkrm", "Dezert"].contains(item._chodnazev) }
}
```

To filter out and return only the elements that match condition we need to wrap our filter in `reduce(into:)` so that the filtering is done once per tuple

```
let result = test.reduce(into: [(key: String, value: [polozkyUcet])]()) {
    let value = $1.value.filter{ item in item._tisk > 0 && ["Předkrm", "Dezert"].contains(item._chodnazev) }
    if value.isEmpty == false {
        $0.append((key: $1.key, value: value))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have an array of polozkhUcet then this should do the trick:

```
someArray.filter  { $0._tisk > 0 && ($0._chodnazev == "Předkrm" || $0._chodnazev == "Dezert") }
```

I could not get your code to run but this works for me:

```
struct polozkyUcet: Codable {
        let _tisk: Int
        var _chodnazev: String
    }

    
    let someArray : [polozkyUcet] = [
        polozkyUcet(_tisk: 1, _chodnazev: "Blah"),
        polozkyUcet(_tisk: 10, _chodnazev: "Předkrm"),
        polozkyUcet(_tisk: 5, _chodnazev: "Dezert"),
        polozkyUcet(_tisk: 0, _chodnazev: "Dezert")
    ]
    
    let selectedElements = someArray.filter  { $0._tisk > 0 && ($0._chodnazev == "Předkrm" || $0._chodnazev == "Dezert") }
```

Comment: Thanks for trying. In my solution I have to use something like let result = sorted_items[].value.filter{$0._tisk > 0} because Array consists of key and value. But I can't put it together :/

Answer (score 0):

Finally I used:

let result = sorted_polozky.map{(key, value) in return value.filter{$0._tisk > 0}}

let filter = result.filter{!$0.isEmpty}

print(filter)

Comment: This answer doesn’t fulfill the requirements in the question so it won’t return the expected results.